# Error in r.thin QGIS GRASS: Input raster must be of type CELL

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, flow-accumulation

I am getting the following error from QGIS GRASS GIS **`r.thin`** module

**ERROR: Input raster must be of type CELL.**

The input file is a simple file of 0 and 1 that represent a drainge network. I obtained it by applying a simple accumulation > value rule to the raster calculator

What can be the problem?

Comment: I remember doing this easily in the QGIS version 2.8 as you wrote without any issue. Now in 2.14 or 2.16 this tool doesn't work for me neither as many other GRASS tools fail to produce results in processing toolbox.  I tried the steps from the answer below and had no luck anyway...

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same problem in GRASS 7. After some deliberation, the following steps did the work

1. If the data type of the raster is FLOAT32, convert the raster using gdal.translate to Int32.This should also solve the error "Input must be of the type CELL.
2. Now run r.null on the raster.
3. The raster layer with non-null values is now ready to be thinned using r.thin

Answer (score 4):

The image should be 1 bit/pixel (0/1 values doesn't guarantee that). Use gdal_translate to change (tiff or png format will fit).

```
gdal_translate -co "NBITS=1" image.tif bit_image.tif
```

Change the background color to null

```
r.null map=image setnull=1
```

After r.thin should work.

Comment: Is there any tool for doing it? I am not exper fo command line instructions

Comment: QGIS may help. GDAL utilities are available (gdal_translate), but the creation option (-co) should be typed in manually. QGIS GRASS plugin is another option for r.null and r.command or the processing toolbox (I didn't check weather r.null is available there).

Answer (score 2):

As Zoltan writes, this has to do with the data type.  There is also a difference between r.thin in GRASS 6 and GRASS 7 that might cause problems.  The following approach should solve both these issues.

In QGIS a raster data set can be prepared for the GRASS 7 version of r.thin by using the GDAL `Raster calculator` that is available in the QGIS Processing toolbox.

The approach makes sure that the data type is accepted by r.thin and that the correct cells are considered for thinning:

1) Set `Input layer A` to your raster layer

2) Use for instance the following formulae in `Calculation in gdalnumeric syntax ...`:
`1*(A>0)`

3) Set `Set output nodata value` to 0 (in GRASS 6, r.thin thins cells with non-0 values, but in GRASS 7, r.thin thins cells with non-null values)

4) Set `Output raster type` to Byte (fixes the data type issue).