# Converting raster to vector by generating center lines?

Tags: qgis, vectorization

I have a binary raster containing boundary pixels with the value 1 (white) and no-boundary pixels with the value 0 (black):

[image]

I would like to vectorize the raster by keeping one center line trough the boundary pixels. However, most polygonize methods I tried (e.g., gdalogr:polygonize, result in two lines around the outline of the boundary pixels (red lines) or no output (saga:gridskeletonization):
[image]

Did I miss any method with which this can be easily done? Or do I have to vectorize the raster first to a vector layer containing two parallel lines and find a way from there to skeletonize/centerline the two lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now it worked for me as @RoVo suggested before. The problem were the no-data values in my input raster. I changed these not with gdal_translate as @AndreJ suggests (in comments of answer above), but with GRASS r.mapcalc.
Here the modules that I used:

#### Replace all no data values:

```
processing.runalg('grass:r.mapcalculator',
                  {"amap": gPb_rlayer,
                   "formula": "if(A>0, 1, null())",
                   "GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                   "GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER": 1,
                   "outfile": mapcalc})
```

#### Thin raster layer to thin non-null cells:

```
processing.runalg('grass7:r.thin',
                  {"input": mapcalc,
                   "GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                   "output": thinned})
```

#### Raster to vector conversion:

```
processing.runalg('grass7:r.to.vect',
                  {"input": thinned,
                   "type": 0,
                   "GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER": 2,
                   "GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                   "output": centerlines})
```

[image]

Comment: This worked in QGIS as well, although r.thin took like an hour to complete.

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

[GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) is able do this.

You need two steps:

1. [r.thin](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.thin.html)

> Thins non-null cells that denote linear features in a raster map layer.

2. [r.to.vect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.to.vect.html)

> Converts a raster map into a vector map.

Comment: Works for me after setting a nodata value to the raster with `gdal_translate -a_nodata`.

Comment: @RoVo s solution didn't entirely work for me. I was able to start `r.thin` after converting the binary raster with `gdal_translate -ot INT32 src_dataset dst_dataset`. It seems that similar conversions are often required before applying `r.thin` to avoid the error **ERROR: Input raster must be of type CELL** [see following link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197145/error-in-r-thin-qgis-grass-input-raster-must-be-of-type-cell). However, when running `r.to.vect` on the raster created with `r.thin`, GRASS always stops working even when applied to small extents of the raster.

Comment: That seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Now it worked for me as @RoVo suggested. The problem were the no-data values. I changed these not with `gdal_translate` as @AndreJ suggests, but with `mapcalc`. I will post my answer containing the modules I used as a separate answer below.

Comment: Came here with this issue some time later, having tried various centerline processes - but this GRASS solution worked PERFECTLY - thanks @RoVo