# Converting raster to line vector layer

Tags: python, line, software-recommendations, raster-conversion, vectorization

I would like to convert all values having the value 1 in a binary raster to a line vector layer. The following image shows the binary raster (`1=white` and `0=black`):

[image: binary raster]

The optimal output would look like the red lines in the following image (which I realized by modifying the GDAL script [raster to vector line](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#raster-to-vector-line)):

[image: raster to lines]

However, this is very slow and not applicable on large rasters. Is there a similar open-source implementation (callable in Python) that does the same with less processing time?

Would it decrease the processing time of the GDAL script [raster to vector line](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#raster-to-vector-line) when writing each single `wkbLineString` to a shapefile instead of adding them all to a `wkbMultiLineString` before writing them to a shapefile?

The only related posts I found so far are referring to polygonizing the raster (which I realized with GRASS GIS [r.to.vect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.to.vect.html)), which creates polygons and thus two lines, where I need only one:

[image: raster to polygons]

Comment: Hi Sophie. You asked a very similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251360/converting-raster-to-vector-by-generating-center-lines/251361#251361) which you could solve. What is the difference now? Are these lines really just one pixel wide or do you need to run `r.thin`?

Comment: Hi @RoVo. Bascially now, I am looking for a more stable and faster solution. When I run those commands on my new data, `r.mapcalculator` does not produce any result, I didn't succeed yet in setting a nodata value with 'gdal_translate', so `r.thin' only produces one line of pixels. Also I am now asked to avoid GRASS modules. Converting a raster to a line vector seems such a 'normal' geoprocessing issue to me that I thought it might be worth asking if there is already something available. The white pixels are just one pixel wide, not sure if you mean that.

Answer (score 1):

WhiteboxTools' [`RasterToVectorLines`](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/data_tools.html?highlight=rastertove#rastertovectorlines) function might be what you're looking for.