# How to load data into R via PyGRASS?

Tags: python, grass-gis, pygrass

I have a remote machine where my GRASS binaries (7.8) are available and I want to apply this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255899/36712 to my data set of thousands of small images. In most PyGRASS tutorials I find the API works more like an remote to the GUI, in other words you apply functions to layers present in the GrassGUI for example `gscript.parse_command('r.univar', map='elevation', flags='g')` where I apply the function `r.univar` to the layer `elevation`
I allready found the `grass-session` [libary](https://github.com/zarch/grass-session) allowing me to create a session without "starting" GRASS. Most of the tutorials I find are also either old referring to Python 2.7 or don't realy cover how to load a dataset or what would even better how I could pass a variable containing the file object to GrassGIS. How I imaging the code should look like is this:

```
from grass_session import Session

with Session(gisdb="/tmp", location="location", create_opts="EPSG:4326"):
    for png in list_of_png_files:
        geo_tiff = transform_png_to_geotiff_with_gdal(png)

        #either i need to do this:
        Loaded_geotiff = load_geotiff_with_grass(geo_tiff)

        #or I can work directly with the geo_tiff Variable
        output = processing.runalg('grass:r.mapcalculator',geo_tiff)
        thined = processing.runalg('grass7:r.thin',output)
        lines = processing.runalg('grass7:r.to.vect',thined)

        save_lines_to_shp(lines)
```

How can I achieve this? The PyGRASS API seems so counterintuitive and it's hard to understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I know tried with `gs.run_command('r.external',input="./data/gtifs/13.tif",output="layer_1")` but i just get an error `CalledModuleError: Module run None r.external input=./data/gtifs/13.tif output=layer_1 ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer for what i wanted to do

```
import tempfile
import glob
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import raster as r
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import vector as v
from grass_session import Session

# glob.iglob gives me an glob itterator without reading the whole dir first
for i,png in enumerate(glob.iglob('/path_to_tiles/*/*.png'), recursive=False)):

    # creates the geotiff as an temp file to reduce the data waste
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir="./data/tmp_dir/") as tmp_geo_tif:

        # calls the function that transforms the png to a geotiff
        transform_to_geotiff(png,tmp_geo_tif.name)

        # because no grassgis instnace is runnig we must create one this is done with the sessions libary
        with Session(gisdb="./tmp", location="location", create_opts="EPSG:4326"):

            # we allways need a internal representation of the data_set we are working with 
            # here in the first step it is layer_1
            curr_raster='layer_1'

            # r. links to the shortcuts and this one links to the external raster import libary
            # it is opening the temp file containing the geotiff
            r.external(input=tmp_geo_tif.name, output=curr_raster, overwrite=True)

            # for mapcalc to work properly we need to set the region to the region of the active layer
            g.region(raster=curr_raster)

            # this results in the layer 'mapcalc' containing either the value of curr_raster or no data 
            # if the cell in curr_raster is bigger than 0 (transforms zero to nodata basicaly)
            r.mapcalc(f'mapcalc = if({curr_raster} > 0, layer_1, null())', overwrite = True)

            # r.thin fails if the raster after map calc only has no data cells thats why we need a try/except
            try:

                # r.thin takes the mapcalc and thins the raster lines to 1 pixel width
                r.thin(input='mapcalc', output='thinned', overwrite=True)

                # r.to_vect then transformst them into polylines
                r.to_vect(input='thinned', output='lines',type='line', overwrite = True)

                # lasty we save it to a gdpk
                output = f'./data/lines_gdpk/lines_{i}.gdpk'
                v.out_ogr(input='lines', output=output, overwrite = True)
            except:
                pass
```