# How to convert raster to vector by generating center lines?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, vector, vectorization

[image]

I need to vectorize the raster by keeping one center line trough the boundary pixels. My solution would need to be very similar to this question: [Converting raster to vector by generating center lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251360/converting-raster-to-vector-by-generating-center-lines)

I tried the provided solution.

**Replace all no data values**:

```py
from qgis import processing

expression = "if(A>0, 1, null())"
input = "input_raster.tif"
output = "mapcalc"

parameters = {
    "expression": expression,
    "a": input,
    "output": output
}
processing.run("grass7:r.mapcalc.simple", parameters)
```

This returns a black image, the issue might be with the expression?

**Thin raster layer to thin non-null cells**:

```py
from qgis import processing

input = "mapcalc"
output = "thinned" 

parameters = {
    "a": input,
    "output": output
}
processing.run("grass7:r.thin", parameters)
```

**Raster to vector conversion**:

```py
from qgis import processing

input = "thinned"
output = "centerlines" 
type = "line"

parameters = {
    "a": input,
    "output": output,
    "type": type
}
processing.run("grass7:r.to.vect", parameters)
```