# Using r.thin in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, digital-image-processing

I am new to GRASS GIS. I need to run my program with the r.thin command, and I will not get any results as I proceed according to the program. My map is a png image in 2 bits.

How do I execute this command correctly?

My input image in "png" format is as follows:
[image]

And my output image after executing the "r.thin" command is as follows:
[image]

As it is clear, no thinning has been done and only the color of the image has changed.

Comment: Hi saeed and welcome GIS SE. You should provide more details, otherwise your question probably will get closed. Describe in detail what you tried to do and at what point you got stuck. Adding a screenshot is always a good idea. Take the [tour] to get more information about how to ask a good question.

Comment: Have a look at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.thin.html and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197145/error-in-r-thin-qgis-grass-input-raster-must-be-of-type-cell to see if there is some information that helps you. If not, as mentioned before, be more detailed, including error message.

Comment: Probably you didn't set the https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region to the map, please take a look at the wiki page.

Comment: If you want to thin the streets, then importantly the *data* are the streets and the buildings etc are to be no-data (from your example it seems to be the opposite).